# Why is this index function showing a 2 instead of a 4?

Tags: python, indexing

When I am running the following code, I get 0,1,2,3,2 to be printed out. Why would a 2 be printed as the last number when it should be a 4? The index function should be printing the index of each of the lists inside of the big list, correct? Using Python btw

```
 game_board = [["o", 1, 0, 0, 0],  
              [2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
              [0, 0, 2, "o", 2],
              [0, 0, 2, 2, 2]]

for i in game_board:
    print(game_board.index(i))
```

Comment: Well, `index()` goes and finds the *first* match it can.

Comment: "index" returns the index of the first matching item (one of the inner lists) in the outer list. Items 2 and 4 are equal, so 2 matches first.

Comment: because for the `[0, 0, 2, 2, 2]` is at two positions ->2 and 4. index will choose first one i.e 2

Answer (score 0):

using the index function of a list returns the first occurrence of an item. Here's a simplified example:

```
game_board = [0,2,5,2,3]
game_board.index(2)
>>> 1
```

This returns the first time the number two is seen in your list.

In your example, the row

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
```

is at index 2 and index 4. When iterating over each list and looking for it's index, rows 0, 1, 2, and 3 return correctly but because the row at index 4 is the same at index 2, it will return the number 2.